# Change Color of Header Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Okay, so I've scoured the net for this but no dice. I am trying to change the background color of my header row in my dataframe to blue.

My code:

```
def color_blue(val):
    color = 'blue'
    return['background-color: blue']

s = wci_fmo.iloc[:0].style.apply(color_blue)
s
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: Function <function color_blue at 0x000000000BD0F730> returned the wrong shape.
>   Result has shape: (7,)
>   Expected shape:   (0, 7)

Please help! I have numpy, pandas, and seaborn imported.

Comment: Apperently, the way to do this is to use a package, like openpyxl, style it, then pass to an outside file. 

I have not attempted it yet, but it is my only option(s) right now. I'm actually shocked this can't be done with pandas and seaborn. It may not be that bad however, I was hoping to present it from the Ipython console, or print out a spreadsheet presentation directly from the console. It is likely that I still can. I will return with alternate solution when finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backgroundColor instead background-color. The first is for javascript, DOM manipulation. The second one is for CSS style declaration.

Comment: thanks, i just omitted it, as it would not accept "backgroundColor"